# javascript getelementsByClassName - undefined []

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

**Background**: I bought this WordPress plugin for event bookings. Apparently the author did not feel it was necessary for things like price updates after adding more than 1 ticket or applying coupons and so I am trying to write a quick and dirty solution myself. The price it charges is correct, but I think people should see the final price before submitting their credit cards. You can see this in action here (just try adding more than 1 ticket) https://hellbentbbq.ca/events/ultimate-pork/

My quick and dirty hack approach is to 
1) Watch for the ticket select to change
2) Watch for coupon code to be successful

I am starting with #1 and trying to get the following to work:

```
`document.getElementsByClassName('em-ticket-select').onchange=function(){ updatePrice() };
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('em-ticket-select'));

function updatePrice(){
        price=document.getElementById('theprice');
        alert(price);
}
`
```

I've added the console.log just so I can understand specifically what I am selecting, but for some reason I can't seem to select any of the items in the html collection?

I thought I could go:

document.getElementsByClassName('em-ticket-select')[0] and get the element I want but apparently not - result is undefined. Without [0] here is what is logged to the console:

```
HTMLCollection[0]
0
:
select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
em-ticket-spaces-5
:
select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
em_tickets[5][spaces]
:
select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
length
:
1
onchange
:
()
__proto__
:
HTMLCollection
```

Any direction on where I am going wrong is appreciated.

I realize it would be easier if I could select the element by ID, but the ID is dynamically generated and I am really just trying to make a quick dirty bolt on JS to solve this instead of rewriting or trying to figure out what someone else was doing in their code.

Comment: can you show your html code? it will be clear that you wrong or else?

Comment: possibly helpful to assign the elements to a variable and then call the index of that array. Need a bit more of an example as was just asked.

Comment: if you want to get value then use this $('#theprice').html();
or use this code

var price= document.getElementById("theprice").innerHTML;

Comment: Your code is run before the element is created (updatePrice.js is in the `<head>`), so the element doesn't exist in the DOM yet. Use an onload/ready event to know when the DOM has finished loading

Comment: Looking at it now I think this is bang on. Going to try your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attach an event listener on the array like object returned via `getElementsByClassName`, loop through them and attach the listener to each one.

```js
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('em-ticket-select');
function updatePrice(el) {
  console.log(el.value);
}
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  selects[i].addEventListener('change',function() {
    updatePrice(this);
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="em-ticket-select">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<select class="em-ticket-select">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<select class="em-ticket-select">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but it's not working. If I dump the length of selects I get 0, but if I log the contents of selects to console I get : 

HTMLCollection[0]
0: select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
em-ticket-spaces-5 : select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
em_tickets[5][spaces] : select#em-ticket-spaces-5.em-ticket-select
length : 1
__proto__ :HTMLCollection

Comment: got this working following someone elses suggestion to push script load to footer using the wp_register_function script.